# Trying to emulate microphone (javax.sound.sampled)

Tags: java, audio, audio-recording

I'm trying to play a sound as it is going from my microphone. Code successfully worked with speakers, but not with my mic.

I am using SourceDataLine & writing to it from file (.wav). Code only works when I choose speakers for mixer. How can I play sound as it is going from my microphone?

```
public void playSound(String fileName, String micName) {
    Mixer mixer = getMixer(micName);
    if (mixer == null) {
        return;
    }
    File file = new File(fileName);
    DataLine.Info info = null;
    SourceDataLine source = null;
    AudioInputStream stream = null;
    byte[] buffer = null;
    try {
        stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        System.out.println(stream.getFormat().toString());
        info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, stream.getFormat());
        source = (SourceDataLine) mixer.getLine(info);
        source.open(stream.getFormat());
        buffer = stream.readAllBytes();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    source.start();
    source.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    source.drain();
    source.close();
}

private Mixer getMixer(String micName) {
    for (Mixer.Info info: AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()) {
        if (info.getName().equals(micName)) {
            return AudioSystem.getMixer(info);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I try to write this SourceDataLine to microphone mixer, I get a

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (Line unsupported: interface
>   SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono,
>   2 bytes/frame, little-endian)

but using speakers doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: I'm confused by what you are doing and trying to do, and don't have much experience with working with mike inputs. But I'm pretty confident that if you want to capture input from a microphone, the class used for this is a TargetDataLine, not a SourceDataLine. An SDL would still be needed for outputting to the speakers, regardless of where the audio data is coming from (file or microphone). You'll have to move the data from the TDL to the SDL if you want to go as directly as possible from mike to speakers.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner I am trying to play sound as it is going from my microphone, so I need to write to microphone's SDL directly from file

Comment: I still don't understand. With a microphone, we read from it, not write to it. Why would you ever write TO a microphone? Are you trying to use it as if it were a speaker? Have you seen the following tutorial. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html